# Join mp4 files in linux

Tags: mp4, concatenation, join

I want to join two mp4 files to create a single one. The video streams are encoded in h264 and the audio in aac. I can not re-encode the videos to another format due to computational reasons. Also, I cannot use any GUI programs, all processing must be performed with Linux  command line utilities. FFmpeg cannot do this for mpeg4 files so instead I used MP4Box:

```
MP4Box -add video1.mp4 -cat video2.mp4 newvideo.mp4
```

Unfortunately the audio gets all mixed up. I thought that the problem was that the audio was in aac so I transcoded it in mp3 and used again MP4Box. In this case the audio is fine for the first half of `newvideo.mp4` (corresponding to `video1.mp4`) but then their is no audio and I cannot navigate in the video also.

My next thought was that the audio and video streams had some small discrepancies in their lengths that I should fix. So for each input video I splitted the video and audio streams and then joined them with the -shortest option in FFmpeg.

Thus for the first video I ran:

```
 avconv -y -i video1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 videostream1.mp4
 avconv -y -i video1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:1 audiostream1.m4a
 avconv -y -i videostream1.mp4 -i audiostream1.m4a  -c copy -shortest  video1_aligned.mp4
```

Similarly for the second video and then used MP4Box as previously. Unfortunately this didn't work either. The only success I had was when I joined the video streams separately (i.e. videostream1.mp4 and videostream2.mp4) and the audio streams (i.e. audiostream1.m4a  and audiostream2.m4a) and then joined the video and audio in a final file. However, the synchronization is lost for the second half of the video. Concretely, there is a 1 sec delay of audio and video. Any suggestions are really welcome.

Comment: "FFmpeg cannot do this for mpeg4 files so instead I used MP4Box" do you mean MP4 file ? do both the audio-video streams uses same encoding parameters (width,height, SPS,PPS, framerate, samplingrate, number of channels ?

Comment: using ffprobe I see that the audio streams have identical attributes. The video streams have the same dimensions but different rates. For the 1st video Video: h264, 720x592, 277 kb/s, PAR 18944:12915 DAR 512:287, 24.97 fps, 45k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc while for the second Video: h264, 720x592, 226 kb/s, PAR 481:330 DAR 39:22, 24.91 fps, 45k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc . Do you believe that this is the source of my problems?

Comment: MP4 supports joining video/audio with different characteristics using different track for different video, but player are not that smart.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415006/ffmpeg-combine-merge-multiple-mp4-videos-not-working

Comment: Your question is already answered in ffmpeg FAQ: http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f

Comment: just love those migrated questions that got later non migrated duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552901/how-to-merge-videos-by-avconv

Comment: See also this even more-popular question: [Stack Overflow: How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232/4561887)

Answer (score 60):

The best way to do this currently is with the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files#demuxer). First, create a file called `inputs.txt` formatted like so:

```
file '/path/to/input1.mp4'
file '/path/to/input2.mp4'
file '/path/to/input3.mp4'
```

Then, simply run this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

See also [concatenation in `ffmpeg` FAQ](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Concatenating-using-the-concat-demuxer).

---

I'm keeping the following here for the benefit of anyone using older versions of ffmpeg.

The latest versions of ffmpeg can do this: you'll have to remux the files into mpeg transport streams first (fairly processor-light, as it's only changing the container format):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts -bsf h264_mp4toannexb middle.ts
```

If that throws up an error [[1](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/384030-ffmpeg-error-mp3-not-supported-by-h264_mp4toannexb)] about h264, you may need to use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb middle.ts
```

You'll have to do this separately with each input file. To concatenate the files together, use:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:middle1.ts|middle2.ts|middle3.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

If that throws up an error about aac, you may need to use

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:middle1.ts|middle2.ts|middle3.ts" -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

If your system supports named pipes, you can do this without creating intermediate files.

```
mkfifo temp0 temp1
```

You'll have to do the following in three separate virtual terminals:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -y temp0
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -y temp1
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:temp0|temp1" -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

If output.mp4 already exists, the third ffmpeg will ask you whether you want to overwrite it, but it will do this *after it has accessed the FIFOs*, and this will make the first to ffmpegs close. So make sure that you choose an unused name for your output file.

This may not work if your input files are different - I believe that differences in bit rate are OK, but frame size, frame rate etc have to match up.

Comment: many thx mate, worked like a charm

Comment: @DaveJarvis Not so; that's a message deliberately and maliciously spread by the libav team, who are a bunch of developers that split from the ffmpeg project to develop avconv (and changed the name because they couldn't secure the copyright on the ffmpeg name). See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv) for a bit more information.

Comment: `*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.` is a message I see now on running `ffmpeg`

Comment: @LordLoh. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: That answer does not answer - how to concatenate mp4 with `avconv`

Comment: Comipled ffmpeg 2.2 as in this video: http://youtu.be/MRrGNIuLJ40  and then everythings works perfectly using the "-f concat -i inputfiles' options. +1

Comment: This also works for mkv files.

Comment: To expand on this, I had to search through a security camera filled with 30s clips for an event and used this command to generate the index file: `find ./ -name *.mp4 | sed -En "s/\.\/*(.*?)$/file '\1'/p" > inputs.txt`

Comment: Keep in mind that neither exif-data nor GPS tracking information from original video clips will be copied

Comment: Doesn't work for me: I get: `[concat @ 0x563ca0173700] Unsafe file name '/media/gabriel/3339-3730/record/20221113/18/31.mp4'
inputs.txt: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I figured it out and [added an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74454448/4561887).

Answer (score 8):

For mp4 the only working solution I found was with MP4Box from gpac package

```
#!/bin/bash
filesList=""
for file in $(ls *.mp4|sort -n);do
    filesList="$filesList -cat $file"
done
MP4Box $filesList -new merged_files_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).mp4
```

or command is

```
MP4Box -cat file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 -new mergedFile.mp4
```

with mencoder and avconv I could'nt make it work :-(

Comment: The command runs without apparent error (it just says creating track video+sound for file1.mp4 and then creating track sound for file2.mp4) .... and then I have no sound in the second part of the resulting video. mp4info says file1 has 1=video 2=audio, file2 has 1=audio, 2=video, maybe that's why...

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one-liner that makes it all that much easier. It does everything needed to be done in order to finally provide you with one resulting video file. Cheers!

```
find *.mp4 | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > list.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4; rm list.txts
```

Comment: There is a typo at the end...  This may work in the current directory.  If you use  `find . -iname "*.mp4" |  sort |  sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > list.txt;  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4; rm list.txt`  you can get files in subdirectories ...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the script dvo. It was a great starting point for me. I had no problem with using named pipes so I adapted the script to use them instead. Plus I fixed it to work with filenames with spaces in them. Output to named pipes does not "go" until you begin reading from them, hence the need to background the initial remux tasks with an & before the final call to avconv. Plus, don't forget to use -c copy, or you end up re-encoding the whole lot.

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in "$@"; do
   TAG=$(echo "$FILE" | sed -e s/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/_/g)
   mkfifo $TAG.mp4concatpipe
   avconv -loglevel "quiet" -i "$FILE"  -f mpegts -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -y $TAG.mp4concatpipe &
   IN=$IN\|$TAG.fifo
done

IN=${IN#\|}
avconv -i concat:$IN -c copy out.mp4
rm *.mp4concatpipe
```

Comment: For some reason this is giving me an "concat:first.m4v.fifo|second.m4v.fifo: No such file or directory" error.. even with quotes (-i concat:"$IN" or -i "concat:$IN"). 

MP4Box suggested in the other answer below however works great!

Comment: Same error when I try it. I wonder if the ".fifo" on line 6 shouldn't be ".mp4concatpipe" instead? This fixes the error for me, but then I get another error.  `Codec 'aac' (86018) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'h264_mp4toannexb'. Supported codecs are: h264 (27) `

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac (macOS 10.13 High Sierra) I used the following with success:

```
for f in *.m4a; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

Reorder as above similarly if necessary (note that the ./ was removed - the path was causing ffmpeg to throw the unsafe file name error).

Then I had to remove the codec and bitrate specified for the default MacPorts ffmpeg to like it:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt  output.m4a
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User!, Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does not answer the original question which was about linux. If you believe that it will work on linux please add that so future readers have a clear understanding, other than that again welcome to superuser and thankyou for your input. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks evilsoup; here is a little script to automate the process, using the more recent `avconv`.
BTW, named pipes did not work for me (output to them got stuck).

```
   #!/bin/bash

    for FILE in $@; do
      avconv -i $FILE -map 0 -f mpegts -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -c:v copy -y $FILE.tmp
      IN=$IN\|$FILE.tmp
    done

    IN=${IN#\|}
    avconv -i concat:"$IN" out.mp4

    for FILE in $@; do
      rm $FILE.tmp
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

Have enjoyed great success with

```
for f in ./*.m4a; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

you may need to reorder mylist.txt slightly

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.m4a
```

ffmpeg version 2.2.3

Comment: I ran this without `-c:a libfdk_aac` and it worked. I tried installing a couple of packages for fdk aac on Ubuntu and it did not work.