# Appending text to a video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to add a blank screen at the end of my video with some white text in the middle (in bold). I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710099/ffmpeg-create-blank-screen-with-text-video) and I would like to do something alike, but the text should be added at the end of my existing video. All the parameters of the video (resolution, bit rate...) should be kept.

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I ended up doing. It's probably not the best solution but it does work :

- I created a 10 second video with the text on it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11139999/1319182) was particularly useful to split the text in multiple lines.
- Then I merged the two videos. I've had a few issues with the containers and [this post](https://superuser.com/a/521852/304534) helped a lot.

I hope this will help someone.